# How to add up all the scores from each round to get a total score

Tags: python

So I'm writing a word game and created several functions.
I have created a function called user_scores() and there are 5 rounds in this game. I have to create a loop to count the total score by each round and I can only show each round's score. Could someone looking for me about this one? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your function,

```
return total_value_in_a_round
```

At the end of OneRound, return the score to the calling program by combining the last two lines:

```
return userscore()
```

In your main program, set up a loop to play 5 times, and keep a running sum of the score:

```
total_score = 0
for round in range(5):
    total_score += OneRound()

print "Your score for 5 rounds is", total_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's only so much I can do without viewing you code, but I'll try to utilize what I can collect from your vague question. In the future, please attempt to give us enough information so that we can actually help you. That would include relevant code snippets(comments are always amazing) and a general explanation of what you want your code to do.

Generally, you can't run a loop for counting the score, and the loop for your game at the same time. You don't want a function, but a variable, and at the end of every round just add the points from that round to the variable. Something like this:

```
    def OneRound():
        #Insert the game code for one round here (Ex:)
        answer = raw_input("Question?")
        if answer == "Bob"
            return 5

    rounds = 0

    while rounds <= 5:
        points = points + OneRound():
        rounds = rounds + 1
```

Your code is good, just use what Prune and I wrote and adapt those two to fit your code. You're missing something that quite a few beginner programmers don't have, and that's a full understanding of loops. Don't worry, with time and practice it will dawn upon you.